# How can I make SWIG return unicode objects for strings in Python 2?

Tags: python, c++, python-2.7, unicode, swig

I have something like the following:

> **swigtest.cpp**

```
#include <string>

class Foo {
public:
    std::string bar() {
        return "baz";
    }
};

inline Foo* new_foo() {
    return new Foo;
}
```

> **swigtest.i**

```
%module swigtest
%{
#include "swigtest.hpp"
%}

%include <std_string.i>
%include "swigtest.hpp"

%newobject new_foo;
```

> **useswig.py**

```
from swigtest import new_foo

foo = new_foo()
print(foo.bar())
print(type(foo.bar()))
```

> ```
> $ swig -c++ -python -modern swigtest.i
> $ g++ -fpic -shared -I/usr/include/python2.7 -DSWIG_PYTHON_2_UNICODE swigtest_wrap.cxx -lpython2.7 -o _swigtest.so
> $ python2 useswig.py
> baz
> <type 'str'>
> ```

Is there any way to get that to output

> ```
> <type 'unicode'>
> ```

instead?  I understand from the [docs](http://www.swig.org/Doc3.0/Python.html#Python_2_unicode) that

> When the SWIG_PYTHON_2_UNICODE macro is added to the generated code ... Unicode strings will be successfully accepted and converted from UTF-8, but note that they are returned as a normal Python 2 string

Is there a way to achieve that, possibly with a custom typemap somehow?

Comment: Thank you for an good [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  I had to tweak it slightly for Windows, but still +1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A custom typemap works, but you'll need more to handle input parameters, output arguments, etc.

```
%module swigtest
%{
#include "swigtest.hpp"
%}

//%include <windows.i>  // Need for Windows DLLs to handle __declspec(dllexport)
//%include <std_string.i>
%typemap(out) std::string %{
    $result = PyUnicode_FromString($1.c_str());
%}

%include "swigtest.hpp"

%newobject new_foo;
```

Output:

```
C:\test>py -2 useswig.py
baz
<type 'unicode'>
```

Comment: Great!  If I'm using the same .i for multiple language bindings, how can I make that typemap only apply to Python?

Comment: @TavianBarnes Sure, `#ifdef SWIGPYTHON` around it.  Other languages are listed in the documentation.